# Can you use 'require' in react to import a library?

Tags: json, reactjs, xml

In my react project, I'm trying to convert XML data from an API call into JSON (using a library called xml-js).

As per the documentation, I'm importing the library in my parent component as follows

```
const convert  = require('xml-js')
```

and then attempting the convert the API data as follows

```
const beerList = 

'<Product>
<Name>Island Life IPA</Name>
<Volume>300ml/473ml</Volume>
<Price>$10/$13</Price>
<ABV>6.3%</ABV>
<Handpump>No</Handpump>
<Brewery>Eddyline</Brewery>
<IBU/>
<ABV>6.3%</ABV>
<Image>islandlife.png</Image>
<Country>New Zealand</Country>
<Description>Fruited IPA</Description>
<Pouring>Next</Pouring>
<IBU/>
<TapBadge/>
<Comments/>
</Product>'

const beerJs = convert(beerList,{compact: true, spaces: 4})
```

The errors are telling me that 'convert' is not a function, which tells me that the library isn't being imported. So is the issue with using 'require' syntax, and if so, what alternative would work in react?

Comment: Read the docs bro. That's not how you use it: https://github.com/nashwaan/xml-js#quick-start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which tells me that the library isn't imported

No. If that were the case, you wouldn't even get that far, your `require` call would throw an error.

Instead, it tells you that `convert` is not a function - which it isn't! Look at it in a debugger or log it, and you'll see it's an object with several functions inside. You can't call an object like a function.

Take a look at the `xml-js` [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js#api-reference) again:

> This library provides 4 functions: `js2xml()`, `json2xml()`, `xml2js()`, and `xml2json()`. Here are the usages for each one (see more details in the following sections):
>
> ```js
> var convert = require('xml-js');
> result = convert.js2xml(js, options);     // to convert javascript object to xml text
> result = convert.json2xml(json, options); // to convert json text to xml text
> result = convert.xml2js(xml, options);    // to convert xml text to javascript object
> result = convert.xml2json(xml, options);  // to convert xml text to json text
> ```

So the solution is to call `convert.xml2json` and not `convert`:

```js
const beerJs = convert.xml2json(beerList, {compact: true, spaces: 4})
```

Or maybe you want an actual object and not a JSON string, then you'd use `convert.xml2js` (in which case the `spaces` option is useless):

```js
const beerJs = convert.xml2js(beerList, {compact: true})
```